# How to POST data to a URL from NestJs code?

Tags: post, nestjs, nestjs-passport

I have a login form with username and password. I'm trying to validate these credentials using the Nest Js authentication strategy [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication). So in the corresponding auth.service.ts file, I'm using "nativescript core modules http" to do a POST request to OAuth URL to validate credentials . But this doesn't work:

```
        import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
        import { request } from "tns-core-modules/http";

        const OAUTH_URL = 'url';

        @Injectable()
        export class AuthService {

        async validateUser(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {

            let data = new FormData();
            data.set('client_id', 'sb-nestjs-app!t36258');
            data.set('client_secret', 'XrHuBRhyvuVNYNJNHlWLgcuBIyc=');
            data.set('username', username);
            data.set('password', password);
            data.set('grant_type', 'password');
            data.set('response_type', 'token');

            request({
                url: OAUTH_URL,
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Accept": "application/json;charset=utf8"
                },
                content: data
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log('response => ' + response + ' statuscode ' + response.statusCode);
                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                    const token = response.content['access_token'];
                    //TODO:
                    // need to send scope also
                    return token;
                }
            }, (e) => {
                console.log('error' + e);
                return null;
            });

            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I run 'nest start' after above code in place, I receive Error: Cannot find module './http-request'

I'm not sure what is going here, I tried "npm install http-request" it didn't work either. **Basically, I need to POST credentials to a OAuth url in NestJs**. Any guidance? Thank you.

Comment: What is `tns-core-modules/http`? Is that a custom module you are using in an organization? Can you print the full stack trace? Have you tried using the provided HttpService from NestJS?

Answer (score 1):

Try with [HttpModule from NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module).
Also you can try [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) from npm, but they deprecated this package. From what I saw on their discussion, the package still works but you will not have support for it, or anything. Here are some [alternatives](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) to it .

I'm not sure you are using the correct `request` npm module. I'm talking about:

```
import { request } from "tns-core-modules/http"
```

Good Luck!